# Akka always timeout waiting for future

Tags: scala, akka

I'm rather new to Akka and trying to figure out how to get a result from my code, I have the following:

```
object MyClass extends Controller {

def createCluster(id: String, uuid: String, loc: String, size: String, quantity: Int, name: String) = { implicit request =>
Async{
Akka.future {
.....
  val system = ActorSystem("System")

  val master = system.actorOf(Props[Master], name = "master")
  val launch = Launch(s, d, request.user, quantity, clusterName)

  //val future = master ? launch
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 minutes)

  val future = Patterns.ask(master, launch, timeout) //master ? launch
  val result = Await.result(future.mapTo[ServerContainer], timeout.duration)
}
}
```

And my main Actor looks like:

```
class Master() extends Actor {

def receive = {
case Launch(server, details, user, quantity, clusterName) => {
  d = details
  s = Some(server)
  u = Some(user)
  q = Some(quantity)
  cname = Some(clusterName)
  hostnameActor ! Host(BIServer.NONE, Server.PDI, Database.NONE, server.uuid.getOrElse(""), None)
}
case Host(bi,etl,db,uuid,name2) => {
  instance = name2
  h = Some(Host(bi,etl,db,uuid,name2))
  templateActor ! TemplateOpts(s.get, d.get, instance.get)
}

case TemplateContainer(client,temp,id, server, _, _, _,_, _) => {
  nodeActor ! TemplateContainer(client,temp,id, server, d.get, h, q, u, cname)}

case NodeContainer(server, details, meta, dns, host, key) => { n = Some(NodeContainer(server,details,meta,dns,host,q))
  etlServerActor ! n.get
}

case ServerContainer(server,details) => {
  sender ! ServerContainer(server, details)
}
}
```

All the actors are executed successfully but the ServerContainer is never returned to the sender even though that line is executed according to the debugger, and the request always timesout after 5 minutes.

Can anyone lend any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sender` you refer to in the scope of  `case ServerContainer` is actually the sender of the `ServerContainer` message and not the original sender of `Launch`

You should hold to some reference of *that* sender as a variable or even better by passing it around with the messages exchange

Comment: Works a treat (and pretty obvious now its spelt out to me ;) ) Thanks!